# Http Listener in .Net Core console app?

Tags: c#, .net, httprequest, .net-core, httplistener

I'm starting to investigate the .net Core and i'm a bit lost.

I'm trying to create a console app which accepts Http requests, like an HttpListener, but it doesn't exists on .net Core.

I've searched a lot and only found some post's referring it will not exist.

So, my question, is it possible to accept Http requests in a .net Core console application?

If yes, with which classes?

Cheers.

Comment: You can use HttpClient in System.Net.Http from .NET Core for sending HTTP requests and receiving HTTP response.

Comment: I don't want to do Http requests, I want to receive them.

Comment: You could implement an HttpListener yourself using Sockets/TcpListener.

Comment: Have a look at  https://github.com/robertsundstrom/HttpListener. I think it can help you.

Comment: I did, but I don't want to use something so untested, I can't understand why .net Core doesn't offers such a functionality.

Comment: @Gusman have you found anything like this? I am also looking for a lightweight listener without the full blown server like kestrel.

Comment: @ShawnMclean No, there isn't, you must use Kestrel. But it's worth it, the speed is amazing. Also, you don't need to use the full kestrel pipeline, that's what I did, just get to the app.Run where you retrieve the context and use the context as you wish to compose the response, at the end is exactly the same functionality as the HttpListener.

Comment: @ShawnMclean to clarify, on the Configure function of your application you get the app and then do `app.Run(async (context) => { /* Whatever */ });` in this way all the pipeline is ignored and only your function processes the requests and responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm cross linking to another answer from 13 May 2017 that seems to have a more updated answer on this topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43954956/1209443

It is saying to use ".NET Core 2.0, which has an [API compatible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=netcore-2.2) [HttpListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=netcore-2.2) that works cross-platform"

Comment: You should add this as a true answer, add the info and the reference to where you have taken it. Else it will be deleted for sure.

Comment: You have posted just a link, that's not how StackOverflow works, you should add the response content and a link to where you have taken the info from. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -1):

To build a self-hosted web application, use installed templates in VS2015 via `New Project -> Templates -> Web -> ASP.NET Core Web Application`.

This wizard creates a self-hosted web application. From the entry `Main` method you can see it uses a `WebHostBuilder`, adds configurations to it (especially the `.UseKestrel` indicates the web server), and runs it.

Besides the template, you can also build your own simple web server. In the `Configure` method in `Startup.cs`, you can use

```
app.Run(async (context) =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
});
```

It allows you to handle the request context and response it.

For more details, check [this article](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-mvc-app/).

Comment: I don't want a web application, I want to create a console application which receives http requests, I don't want to use ASP .net, just plain HTTP requests like HttpListener.

Comment: No, it's an ASP .net core web application, console applications are under Templates -> .net Core -> Console Application.

Comment: @Gusman Why don't you try it your self? Templates only help you add dependencies, generate sample codes. It's compiled to a `.exe` in windows and can be run via command line, not `DLLs` load by web server.

Comment: Console apps are indeed .dll files, not exe's, you can check it... Also, I don't want to use the Asp environment, I just want to receive plain HTTP requests, but I'm starting to think MS just wants to force us to use asp .net and it's just not possible... very bad idea MS.

Comment: @Gusman So how to tell if an application is a console application or web?

Comment: Anything not running inside a WebHost is a console application, if it runs inside a WebHost it's a web application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122253/discussion-between-danny-chen-and-gusman).

Comment: I have checked it and as I thought Web Apps doesn't open a console and can't read keys from it, so they're completely different. Maybe it changed from RC to V1.0?

Comment: He wants to implement an HttpListener so he can implement his own actions. This answer and all the comments completely miss the point.

Answer (score -3):

Play with the code below:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int timeoutInDays = 1;
        Stream dataStream;
        StreamReader reader;

        while(true)
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(timeoutInDays);

                dataStream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync("https://localhost:5001/api/v1/customers/streaming");

                reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                Console.WriteLine(await reader.ReadLineAsync());
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, *I'm trying to create a console app which **accepts** Http requests, like an HttpListener*.  You are showing how to **make** http requests and get the results in a console app.