# What is analog for HttpListener in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm porting application from .NET 4 to .NET Core and can't find analog for HttpListener class

```
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'HttpListener' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Update1

```
        private readonly HttpListener _httpListener;

            if (!HttpListener.IsSupported)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException(
                "The Http Server cannot run on this operating system.");
        }

        _httpListener = new HttpListener();
        _httpListener.Prefixes.Add(prefix);
        _sessionSettings = settings;
```

Comment: WebListener ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/weblistener

Comment: Also there is some simple library on github https://github.com/robertsundstrom/HttpListener

Comment: Suddenly both (WebListener and  github.com/robertsundstrom/HttpListener) don't have some properties and because not compatible

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `WebListener` (in the `Microsoft.Net.Http.Server` NuGet package) is the closest replacement, but has a different API. Alternatively, there is the Kestrel HTTP server, which is best consumed from the ASP.NET Core stack but can be used alone (but that is difficult to set up).

If you are porting, I'd suggest to wait until .NET Core 2.0, which has an [API compatible `HttpListener`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=netcore-2.2&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002999) that works cross-platform and doesn't require you to completely change the code.

Comment: do you have any example how to send a response with `WebListener` after you get a request with `AcceptAsync` ?

Answer (score 9):

In .NET Core 2.0 we don't have that problem ( thanks Martin Ullrich), so now we need install [Visual Studio Preview 2017 version 15.3](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/) where we can use .NET Core 2.0.

But by default (as minimum for now) there don't have .NET Core 2.0 and we need [install it](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848740) after VS 2017 installation.

P.S: - thanks again Martin Ullrich - it's amazing, only 10 May ( 3 days before I have asked) .NET Core 2.0 [was announcing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/05/10/announcing-net-core-2-0-preview-1/) - and I have it now